# how to show only relevant tag on post page

Tags: wordpress

From the tag page I click a post.

When I get to the post page I want to show the relevant tag (the one I clicked).

Problem is that each of my posts has more then one tag. and using get_the_tags() get me the whole list of tags related to the post.

How can I identify and show only the relevant tag from the array?
Is there anyway to pass this information to the single.php page?

Comment: share the code if you have

Answer (score 0):

at the end I passed the tag name with the post URL and used $_GET to read it back on the post page.

on tag page:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>?tagName=<?php single_tag_title(); ?>">
```

on post page:

```
<?php echo $_GET["tagName"]; ?>
```